# Help me with these Spikes

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I need some help. I have to vector this design in Illustrator, this circle with these "spikes". Are there any effects or distortions for me to get the same result? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Yes. I tried to use Blend and after that Roughen to emulate like a "fury", and i used wrinkle tools and etc, but no success

Comment: It's not a regular pattern. I think you have to actually draw it. And then when the lines are done apply some blue or similar. Perhaps it's easier to draw the lines along a straight line and then make it a brush and apply it to a circle.